# Microsoft Graph API for outlook message returns ReadableStream with error statusCode: 401

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, nestjs, outlook-api

I'm integrating outlook api into my app with microsoft graph but it keeps returning my this error instead of giving any error. However, when i do mess up the config it tells me that my config is inavlid.

[image: error image]

the function im using to get microsoft graph

```
async msalSendEmail(
    data: {
      from: string;
      toRecipients: [{ emailAddress: { address: string } }];
      subject: string;
      headers?: [{ 'In-Reply-To': string }, { References: string }];
      body: {
        contentType: string;
        content: string;
      };
    },
    refreshToken: string,
  ) {
    const cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(this.msalConfig);
    const response = await cca.acquireTokenByRefreshToken({
      refreshToken,
      scopes: [
        'user.read',
        'user.read.all',
        'user.readbasic.all',
        'mail.read',
        'mail.readbasic',
        'mail.readwrite',
        'mail.send',
      ],
    });

    const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
      this.msalConfig.auth.tenantId,
      this.msalConfig.auth.clientId,
      this.msalConfig.auth.clientSecret,
    );

    const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
      scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
    });

    const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({
      defaultVersion: 'v1.0',
      debugLogging: true,
      authProvider,
    });

    const message = {
      subject: data.subject,
      body: {
        contentType: 'Text',
        content: data.body.content,
      },
      toRecipients: [
        {
          emailAddress: {
            address: 'example@example.com',
          },
        },
      ],
    };
```

my permissions
[image: microsoft graph permissions]

**Things i tried to solve this issue:**

- Went from Delegate Access to Application Access (doesn't work at all)
- Tried Public oAuth Method
- Tried Confidential oAuth Method
- Tried OnBehalfOf but that is not working as well
- Tried giving all the possible permission
- Created a pump for Readable Stream but that is returning undefined

**Solved**
My solution was to replace the custom tenantid with common in the msal configuration.